# Perfect hash function for large set of integers [1..2^64 - 1]

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, hash-function, perfect-hash

I need to construct a perfect hash function that maps a set of integer [1..2^64 - 1] to itself (this function is actually some some complex permutation).

To explain this problem suppose that we have sequence of integer primary keys in database. We need to show construct a number (which we show to users) in a way that close numbers corresponds to primary keys that as far from one another as possible.

So, basically I need a bijective function for large set of integers. E.g.

- 1 -> X1
- 2 -> X3
- 3 -> X3
- ...
- 2^64 - 1 -> X2^64 - 1

Any suggestions or references will be appreciated.

Comment: what minimal 'distance' between close numbers would be acceptable?

Comment: There is no hard limitations. Basically I need to spread sequential numbers on wider range.

Comment: Modular multiplication by an odd number is bijective and stays in that range (0 maps to itself so if it's not in the input range it's not in the output range)

Comment: If you need to preserve **0**, you can always use **g(x) = f(x) - f(0)** for any bijective function **f**

Comment: Use any convenient encryption function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To space out any two numbers maximally in a space from 0 to `upperlimit` (excluding) i would set their distance to roughly one-half of `upperlimit`.

In python it would look like this (code only works if `upperlimit` is even, otherwise the last element collides):

```
def my_hash(n, upperlimit):
    return n * upperlimit / 2 % upperlimit + n / 2

def my_unhash(n, upperlimit):
    return n % (upperlimit / 2) * 2 + n / (upperlimit / 2)
```

Example result:

```
upperlimit = 16
for i in range(upperlimit):
    h = my_hash(i, upperlimit)
    u = my_unhash(h, upperlimit)
    print "%02d -> %02d -> %02d" % (i, h, u)

00 -> 00 -> 00
01 -> 08 -> 01
02 -> 01 -> 02
03 -> 09 -> 03
04 -> 02 -> 04
05 -> 10 -> 05
06 -> 03 -> 06
07 -> 11 -> 07
08 -> 04 -> 08
09 -> 12 -> 09
10 -> 05 -> 10
11 -> 13 -> 11
12 -> 06 -> 12
13 -> 14 -> 13
14 -> 07 -> 14
15 -> 15 -> 15
```

The second column shows the hashed values. You can exclude the 0 if you want, because it maps to itself.

Comment: not sure how important or not is that requirement, but please note that with dividing the space into 2, you make any 2 consecutive numbers far apart, but by skipping every other number, they are close 0 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 2... same holds for odd numbers. 
Better strategy (if we want to reduce proximity of numbers which are 2 apart) is to divide the available space into N buckets and shuffling the numbers between these. Obviously using N buckets would mean that every Nth number would get close... but by adjusting N (say for 64bit space, use N as 1024 or higher power of 2) would give spread.

Comment: Good points, the requirements are not clear here. I maximized the distance of consecutive numbers.